# can I use same functions with the different type of argument inputs

Tags: matlab, function, input, arguments

If I have a MATLAB lab file contains function `foo`

```
function [test] = foo(a,b);
test = a+b
```

If I want to modified that function foo also receive the addition data `c` in my input
in the same MATLAB file

```
function [test] = foo(a,b,c);
test = a+b+c;
```

Can I do this? (I try the similar but when I try to use it said that I have to many argument.)

Comment: Judging by the function name `foo`, I'm assuming the summation task is just an example and you are doing something else with the additional argument, right?

Comment: NO I just made the function up. my real assignment involve multiplication of matrix but I just want to know is it possible to use the same function but with the different parameters

Comment: Just checking. That's what I thought, and why left the answer generic.  Glad to have helped.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`varargin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html) approach is suitable here, although I would do it slightly differently (see below). However, you can simply test for the existence of the third argument with [`exist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html) (or via `nargin`, but that is less direct and error prone).

### `exist`

```
function test = foo(a,b,c)

if exist('c','var'), % nargin>2
    test = a + b + c;
else
    test = a + b;
end
```

As in the code comment, a test on `nargin` is also possible, but the `exist` call is far less ambiguous and will not need a change if the argument list is modified (e.g. order).

### `varargin`

Note that `varargin` does not need to be the only argument in the function declaration:

```
function test = foo(a,b,varargin)

if nargin>2, % numel(varargin)>0
    test = a + b + varargin{1};
else
    test = a + b;
end
```

Also, say you want to have any number of extra inputs (e.g. `foo(a,b,c,d,...)`), you can do to tricks with the `varargin` cell array.  For instance, you can do `[varargin{:}]` to horizontally concatenate the elements in to an a new array. For vertical concatenation, you can do `vertcat(varargin{:})`. I'm assuming the `a+b+c` example was *just an example*, so I won't show this in practice, but you can use these arrays any way you like.

Comment: Your explanation is good. It makes me understand clearly. Besides, I think I could use the exist to my program. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

you can write in this way:

```
function [test] = foo (varargin)
y = 0 ;
for i = 1:length(varargin)
y = y+ varargin(i) ;
end
test = y ;
end
```

you can supply as many arguments as you want.you can read more about varargin here: [enter link description here](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html)

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the easiest way to support this, is with

```
function [test] = foo (varargin)
  test = sum ([varargin{:}]);
end
```

This will allow for any number of inputs. f you want to limit to 2, 3 inputs, do

```
function [test] = foo (varargin)
  narginchk (2, 3);
  test = sum ([varargin{:}]);
end
```

Another method, if you want to avoid `varargin`, is to set the last element to default to 0 so it doesn't affect the operation in case it is not defined:

```
function [test] = foo (a, b, c = 0)
  test = a + b + c;
end
```

**EDIT**: I am unsure about this, but the above method to set defaults, *may be* Octave only and not yet implemented in Matlab.