# multiple different sized output function?

Tags: matlab, output, variadic-functions

I need to have MATLAB return multiple outputs of different sizes, i.e. one is n by m matrix, the other is a vector

```
function output = name(arg1,arg2,...,argn)

    blabla

    output = {A;B};

end
```

when I type

```
{A;B}=name(arg1,arg2,...,argn)
```

I get this error

> Error: The expression to the left of the equals sign is
>   not a valid target for an assignment.

How do I obtain those multiple outputs? I don't want them printed; I need to use the outputs in further calculations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use the [varargout](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargout.html?refresh=true) option for the function output, which lets you assign (believe it or not) a variable number of outputs.

For example, consider this function:

```
function [varargout] = YourFcn(arg1,arg2)

A = arg1;
B = arg2;

varargout = {A;B};

end
```

Then you can call your function and gather the results like this in the command window or a script for example:

```
x = rand(1,10);
y = magic(5);

[A,B] = YourFcn(x,y)
```

Which results in A and B being assigned the outputs:

```
A =

  Columns 1 through 5

    0.8147    0.9058    0.1270    0.9134    0.6324

  Columns 6 through 10

    0.0975    0.2785    0.5469    0.9575    0.9649


B =

    17    24     1     8    15
    23     5     7    14    16
     4     6    13    20    22
    10    12    19    21     3
    11    18    25     2     9
```

Comment: A note to OP:  You can apply the [same approach to input arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21654075/2778484) (`varargin` and `nargain`) or you can get fancy and use the [`inputParser` class](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20337956/2778484). +1, Benoit

Answer (score 1):

This is what one can do:

```
function [a,b,c,d] =  test(x,y,z)
a = whatever;
b = whatever;
c = whatever;
d = whatever;
end
```